# Handle a click when hyperlinks are not visible

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am new to selenium and trying to automate some web click using selenium and python

There is a link as per below, which opens up dialogue box

```
<li id='upFol'>
<a href='#' title='documents'></a>
.....
</li>
```

I have below code in python

```
upload = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='upFol']/a")))
upload.click()
```

this finds the element and can see the click but dialogue box doesn't get opened

Is there way to handle these kind of scenarios

Comment: Is pop up disabled ?

Comment: @PDHide: also id of the pop up is not visible when I check the -page source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `presence_of_element_located()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li#upFol > a[title='documents']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@id='upFol']/a[@title='documents']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: hi, this worked for me. But at a later stage I am doing the same for another button `WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='submit']"))).click()` but it gives me exception `TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`. I tried putting timer sleep as well. do you have any tips that I can look into? thanks